# How to extend numerical protocols in Clojure

Tags: clojure, protocols

I'm trying to use protocols to create an engineering number type (a "knumber"), so I can say `(+ "1k" "2Meg")` and get something like `"2.001Meg"`.  I should be able to get the floating point value from the knumber like so `(:val my-knumber)`, but normally the printer should display the string, which is also accessible like so `(:string my-knumber)`.  This number will support all the usual p, n, u, m, k, Meg, G suffixes, and convert as required among them, such as `(/ "1Meg" "1G") -> "1m")`.  I want to be able to pass this to any function which expects a number.

Anyway, Can someone suggest a strategy for this?  I think I need to use protocols.  I currently have a `(defrecord knumber [val string])` but I'm not sure what's next.

What protocols do clojure numbers satsify?  I'm thinking I need to extend some existing protocols/interfaces for this.

Thanks

Comment: I know it's not the same thing, but you can just use scientific notation: (/ 1e6 1e9)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your strategy should probably be as follows:

- Define the record `KNumber` as something like `(defrecord knumber [value unit-map])`
- Make `unit-map` a map of units to integer exponents (you are going to want units like m/s^2 if these are engineering numbers, right?). It might look something like `{"m" 1 "s" -2}`,
- Have `KNumber` implement `java.lang.Number` so that you can use it with other mathematical functions that already exist in Clojure. You'll need to implement `doubleValue`, `longValue` etc.
- Define a protocol `NumberWithUnits` that you can extend to both `KNumber`s and normal clojure numbers. At a minimum it should have methods `(numeric-value [number])` and `(get-units [number])`
- Then define your mathematical functions `+`, `*`, `-` etc. in your own namespace that operate on anything that implements the `NumberWithUnits` protocol and return a `KNumber`.
- Regarding different unit scales (e.g. "m" vs. "km") I would suggest standardising on a single scale for internal representation for each unit type (e.g. "m" for distances) but providing options for conversion to other unit scales for input/output purposes.

Comment: How do you "Have `KNumber` implement `java.lang.Number`"?  `defprotocol` only supports implementing interfaces and java's `Number` is an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

The [frinj library](https://github.com/martintrojer/frinj) is a Clojure library for calculations with units. Looking into the source will probably give you some nice ideas.